# Large delay with AWS EventBridge when listening for CodeCommit events

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using EventBridge to invoke a Lambda function whenever a commit is made on my CodeCommit repo. It's a really simple CI/CD solution and it kind of works, except there is a large delay - between 1 and 15+ minutes from the time I make the commit. Here is the EventBridge rule pattern:

```
{
  "source": ["aws.codecommit"],
  "detail-type": ["CodeCommit Repository State Change"],
  "resources": ["arn:aws:codecommit:eu-central-1:...<id>.."],
  "detail": {
    "referenceType": ["branch"],
    "referenceName": ["master"]
  }
}
```

Is there anything at all that I can do to make it react faster to a commit? Is the pattern correct?

Comment: Just to clarify the obvious: by "make a commit" you mean "push a commit", right? Do you see the `GitPush` event in CloudTrail when you push a commit? Does it have the correct timestamp?

Comment: @Quassnoi Yes, I meant when you push a commit. I'm not sure I understand the rest though.

Comment: CloudTrail is the service where AWS logs its API calls. Open it in your AWS console, find or create the default management trail (one per organization  or personal account is free) and see if your commits end up in this trail. A trail is basically a log file stored in S3.